# Как пользователи соц-сети получают доступ к базе данных

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, авторизация

Сейчас я занялся освоением СУБД PostgreSQL и меня волнует вопрос: Как пользователи соц-сетей получают данные у меня в голове 2 варианта:

1. Каждый пользователь добавляется так же в базу данных как новый пользователь с ограниченными правами(но это как я думаю будет очень сильно давить на скорость прогрузки).
2. Каждый пользователь соц-сети , так сказать обращается к одному созданному пользователю базы-данных и он уже выдает данные которые нужны (но сможет ли один пользователь базы данных одновременно обрабатывать сотни запросов).

Comment: никак не получют, потому что не надо это пользователям.

Comment: Вариант 2, формальных ограничений на число запросов нет, только технические (лишь бы железо потянуло). Ну и как уже отмечено в первом комментарии - пользователи соцсети вообще не имеют доступа к базе, они взаимодействуют с каким-нибудь API соцсети, а уже программа, реализующая этот API на стороне соцсети, ходит в базу

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Пользователи никак не получают доступ к БД, в этом нет необходимости, мало того, это небезопасно. Пользователи получают доступ к интерфейсу соц. сети и производят с ним какие-то операции (вводят логин и пароль, например), интерфейс передаёт информацию в backend, а далее уже логика backend'a обращается к БД.